# Difference in opening a file directly and uploading to a web server

Tags: html, testing

Given a simple HTML file is there any difference when testing, in opening it directly by double clicking it or uploading to IIS/Tomcat and accessing localhost/simpleHTML?

Answer (score 0):

In the case of html files it dosenot matter much. Where this matters is when the page is made in languages like php, jsp etc. A webpage containing php or jsp files will not be detected by browsers when directly opened. For this we use webservers like wamp, xampp, lamp, tomcat etc and acces it via localhost/pagename. For more details just view the pagesource of a php file. You wont be able to find and php scripts in it. You will be able to see only the html part in the page. For scripting languages like html, javascript, css etc. opening directly dosent matter.

Hope this is useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

**No**, a simple HTML-only file will not be rendered differently most(99.9%) of the time by opening it directly by double-clicking from the local file system and accessing it from a web server. The only difference will be caused if the file contains any server side language (PHP, ASP etc..)